# How to downsample raster image for nightlights data in Python?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, numpy, rasterio, resampling

I'm working with the nightlights data - 30 arc second grids, spanning -180 to 180 degrees longitude and -65 to 75 degrees latitude.
I want to downsample it to 5 arc-min resolution.

Now my question is how to best do it? I'm using rasterio to load the data and looked at [this](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/resampling.html) way but it does not work for me as I'm using python 3 and get error - "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" I'm also worried as to how it will impact my coordinate systems etc.

I haven't found anything latest on this yet. What's the best way to go about it?

```
nlight_path = "./data/nightlights/F182013.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif"
# open raster data
with rio.open(nlight_path) as src:
    nlight = src.read(masked=True, indexes = 1)
    nlight_meta = src.profile
    nlight_extent = rio.plot.plotting_extent(src)
print(nlight_extent)
print(nlight_meta)
print(nlight.shape)
print(type(nlight))

(-180.00416666665, 180.00416522665, -65.00416610665, 75.00416666665)
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint8', 'nodata': None, 'width': 43201, 'height': 16801, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_dict(init='epsg:4326'), 'transform': Affine(0.0083333333, 0.0, -180.00416666665,
       0.0, -0.0083333333, 75.00416666665), 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'band'}
(16801, 43201)
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
```

Also can I directly do the downsampling on masked array? But then how will it affect the mask?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See the examples referenced here: 
https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1732

```py
with rasterio.open('image.tif') as dataset:
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(dataset.count, dataset.height // 3.75, dataset.width // 3.75), # Integer division using //
        resampling=Resampling.cubic
    )
```

Another simple way to go about it is to use [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray). It is a wrapper around `rasterio`.

Here is an example of what you want to do:

```py
import rioxarray
import xarray

nlight_path = "./data/nightlights/F182013.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif"
rds = xarray.open_rasterio(nlight_path).squeeze().drop("band")
rds.attrs.pop("nodatavals")

downsampled = rds.rio.reproject(rds.rio.crs, resolution=5.0/60.0)
downsampled.rio.to_raster("downsampled.tif")
```

> Also can I directly do the downsampling on masked array?

Pending this [PR](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/pull/31) you will be able to open with `masked=True`. In xarray, it will convert the value to a float64 and fill the mask with a NaN value. But you can easily convert back with the `fillna()` and `astype()` methods.

> But then how will it affect the mask?

The mask should be preserved as close as possible.